# PayPal Adaptive Parallel Payments - send form data to paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the PayPal API for adaptive payments for buying products in my website, when users want to do 'checkout' in the website I transfer them to paypal to login or register in order to complete the payment process. The default option is the register form but the form is empty when redirecting to paypal from my website, is there any way to transfer the registration data (like name, address, email...) to this form from the redirection to paypal so my users wont need to do it twice (in my website and in paypal)?

I know that when using the standard payments this is enabled but I didn't figured it out how to do it with adaptive payments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't an option to pass their registration info via Adaptive Payments Parallel Payments.

You may however want to look into Express Checkout Parallel payments as it will support customer registration details via the API and offers more flexibility. I've listed a sample request below.

This is an "advanced" request. Line item details are not required however is recommended to provide a better checkout experience.

```
USER=
PWD=
SIGNATURE=
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=98.0
RETURNURL=http://www.yoursite.com/mts/pp_nvp_quick_test.php
CANCELURL=http://www.yoursite.com/mts/pp_nvp_quick_test.php
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=Daffy Duck
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=123 looney lane
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2= Apt 7
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Miami
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=FL
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=33010
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=524.20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=458.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=46.20
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=111
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Books
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=154.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ABC123
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=CDs
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=50.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=3
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=receivier@email.com
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTONAME=Daffy Duck
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOSTREET=123 looney lane
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOSTREET2= Apt 7
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOCITY=Miami
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOSTATE=FL
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOZIP=33010
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=494.20
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=428.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=46.20
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=test EC payment
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=222
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME0=DVDs
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT0=154.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NUMBER0=ABC123
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY0=2
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME1=Computers
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT1=40.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY1=3
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=receivier@email.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the problem is that I really need to use adaptive payments in order to split the transaction between several receivers. can I do that with express checkout?

Comment: Yes, Express Checkout Parallel payments works almost identical to Adaptive Payments Parallel payments and has more features. If passing registration data to PayPal is vital, Express Checkout Parallel payments is the way to go.